# How to split a text file in parts and rejoin them again later (in python)?

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

I want to know how to split a single txt into different parts (depending on the size of the file) and store it in different files for execution.

Once the execution is completed for every file I would like to know how to merge those back to a single file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: you could use os tools without any coding

Comment: os module worked what i wanted thank u so... Zagorulkin Dmitry

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you're on *nix.

```
 man split
```

and

```
 man cat
```